# D Style Arrays to C Style Arrays

Tags: arrays, pointers, d

I am creating a Window in D, and the `CreateWindowA` function requires pointers to characters, C character arrays basically.

How do I convert a D style array (`char[]`) to a C style array (`char*`)?

Comment: "code that enjoys risking buffer overruns can scare the pointer out of the array (by using `arr.ptr`)" - from the official tutorial, found after 2 minutes of googling.

Comment: @H2CO3 That usually is a bad idea, because D strings aren't null-terminated, and C strings normally are. Passing `ptr` to a C function only works when it also takes the length and won't look for a null-terminator in the array that it's passed.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis Exactly (but passing an explicit length is often a better idea anyway...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two functions to look at are normally [`std.string.toStringz`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#toStringz) and [`std.utf.toUTFz`](http://dlang.org./phobos/std_utf.html#toUTFz).

`toStringz` will convert `string` to `immutable(char)*`, which you can pass to a C function which takes `const char*`. If it can determine that the `string` is null-terminated (which usually is only the case for string literals, which have a null terminator one passed their end), then it won't allocate and will just use the `string`'s `ptr` property, but in most cases, it will allocate.

`toUTFz` will convert from any string type to any character pointer type. It's probably most frequently used for converting to `const(wchar)*` for Windows, since all of the `W` functions for Windows take UTF-16, but it can also be used to convert to `char*` - e.g. `str.toUTFz!(char*)()`. Like `toStringz`, it will try not to allocate if it can determine that it's unnecessary, but it's almost always necessary.

Now, for your particular case, you're trying to use one of the `A` functions in Windows. This is almost always a bad idea, and I would strongly advise against it. Use `toUTFz` to convert your `string` to `const(wchar)*` and pass that to `CreateWindowW`. AFAIK, the only advantage to the `A` functions is that they work with pre-Win2K. Everything else about them is worse. However, if for some reason, you insist on using the `A` functions, then you're going to have to use [`std.windows.charset.toMBSz`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_windows_charset.html#toMBSz), because the `A` functions don't take UTF-8 but rather the "Windows 8-bit character set," and `toMBSz` will convert the string to that format.

Comment: The reason I'm using the Windows-ASCII functions is because I cannot find the wide functions inside the `core.sys.windows.windows` module, so I concluded D doesn't have those implemented.

Comment: @JeroenBollen All that's required is the function prototype, so if druntime doesn't have it for some reason, you can just declare it yourself. However, most D programmers doing much with the Windows API use http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/WindowsApi which is much more complete than what druntime has.

Comment: So I could just do something like `extern(Windows) void* CreateWindowW(...);`, and it'd work? No external libraries needed to be linked or modules to be included?

Comment: @JeroenBollen You'll have to link everything exactly like you'd have to do in C++. You're basically doing exactly what you'd do in C or C++ except that you need to do the prototype yourself, because you can't just include the C header, and you have to convert the string type when passing it to the function, because D's native string type isn't the same as C's. You can get more info at http://dlang.org/windows.html and http://dlang.org/htomodule.html

Comment: I already have `user32.lib` passed to my linker, yet it still errors in `Symbol Undefined _CreateWindowW@44`.

Answer (score 3):

you grab the `ptr` field of the D array. and the `length` field to grab the length

however if you need a C-style string then you need the [`toStringz`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.toStringz) method that will add the null terminator and return the pointer to the first char. `k`eep a reference to it if the api doesn't create it's own copy to operate on to avoid dangling pointers by GC

Comment: In general, this is correct. However, for the Windows `A` functions, it isn't, because while they take `char`, they don't use UTF-8. You need `std.windows.charset.toMBSz` for them.